# Unable to update with dnf because of a GPG check FAILED

Tags: linux, fedora, gnupg, brave, dnf

Since last week I can´t update anything. If I try `sudo dnf update`, the process starts normally but then I get the following error:

```
error: Verifying a signature using certificate D8BAD4DE7EE17AF52A834B2D0BB75829C2D4E821 (Brave Software <support@brave.com>):
  Key A8580BDC82D3DC6C invalid: key is not alive
      because: The subkey is not live
      because: Expired on 2023-05-06T16:53:34Z
```

This is repeated several times and I get the following final error:

```
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.. Failing package is: brave-browser-1.51.118-1.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: 
Public key for brave-keyring-1.11-1.noarch.rpm is not trusted. Failing package is: brave-keyring-1.11-1.noarch
 GPG Keys are configured as: 
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED
```

Nothing else is updated. I even tried to remove the cached files as suggested, but nothing gets removed.

Any ideas what might be causing this and how to fix it?

I'm running Fedora 38.

Comment: Did you read the first message/cause? "because: Expired on 2023-05-06T16:53:34Z"

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes, but I assumed it was expired on the repo, not on my side. If I'm the one supposed to fix it, can you provide some pointers on how to do it?

Comment: @harrymc Correct. I fixed the typo

Comment: Yes, it must be corrected on server side,

Comment: Did my answer help @nbneo?

Answer (score 4):

It's a [recent issue](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/30307) of Brave Browser and its expired key.

You can try completely uninstalling the package and removing the old key file:

- find key ID with `rpm -q gpg-pubkey --qf '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\t%{SUMMARY}\n'`
- remove with `sudo rpm -e gpg-pubkey-[keyId]`.

Then [reinstall](https://brave.com/linux/#fedora-centos-streamrhel) with the new key:

> `sudo rpm --import https://brave-browser-rpm-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc`
>
> `sudo dnf install brave-browser`

Answer (score 0):

You can re-import fedora gpg key:

```shell
curl https://fedoraproject.org/fedora.gpg | sudo gpg --import
```